# Is it possible to install dlib on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, dlib

I am trying to create a face recognition system but most of the approaches require the dlib library ..is it possible to install dlib on windows?

Comment: What does your question have to do with OpenCV?

Comment: Have you tried installing it under Windows - the process is described on the `dlib` website, so is there some reason to believe it is not possible? Have you tried?

Comment: i couldnt find any infor about Windows 7 only 10 and some say it is not supported in windows

Answer (score 4):

If you want a fast answer, **yes** it is.

For more info, you have to follow the next steps:

1. **Install Visual Studio 2015**
2. **Install CMake**
3. **Install Anaconda 3**
4. **Download Dlib**

   You can download it from [here](http://dlib.net/)
5. **Build it**

   Unzip the file and then open a PowerShell. Use the following commands:

   ```
   cd dlib-19.16/
   mkdir build
   cd build

   #This is a only command
   cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=..\dlib\external\libjpeg -DJPEG_LIBRARY=..\dlib\external\libjpeg -DPNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR=..\dlib\external\libpng -DPNG_LIBRARY_RELEASE=..\dlib\external\libpng -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=..\dlib\external\zlib -DZLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE=..\dlib\external\zlib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install ..

   cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
   ```

   Dlib will be installed in "dlib-19.16\build\install". There will be include and library folders which you can specify in Visual Studio to build projects using Dlib
6. **Update enviroment variable**

   Create a new User Variable called "dlib_DIR"  and whose value is the full path of "dlib-19.16\build\install". **Note:** Close any PowerShell/ComandPrompt to update the system variables.
7. Build Dlib Examples
   I use the edited version of CMakeList of LearnOpenCV (you can find it [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/CMakeLists.txt)). Then use this commands:

   ```
   cd dlib-19.16/examples
   makedir build
   cd build

   cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
   cmake --build . --config Release
   ```
8. **Install Python Module**

   Compiling Python bindings for Dlib from source isn't as easy. You have to compile Boost.Python from scratch and configure some environment variables (such as BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR) before you can compile Python module of Dlib. I'm skipping that part for now. Just one more command to Anaconda 3.

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.4
   ```

And that's all, you have to have your Dlib in your Anaconda 3. I hope to have helped you.